# How to pass symbol as parameter of post request in ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, symbols

This code work well

```
Geokit::default_units = :miles #:kms, :nms, :meters
```

But this code make errors

```
puts params[:unit]     # miles
Geokit::default_units = params[:unit] #:miles, :kms, :nms, :meters
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: What error? are you using Rails?

Comment: I am using Padrino ruby framework.

Comment: your title describes "parameter of a post request", but your shown code doesn't mention anything about making a post request, or where you got `params` from, which makes it difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all that goes through the params is an string, if you want a symbol, then consider using .to_sym:

```
params = { unit: 'miles' }
p params[:unit].class # String
p params[:unit].to_sym.class # Symbol
```

Answer (score 3):

have you confirmed that `params[:unit]` is actually a symbol, and not a string?

```
 Geokit::default_units = params[:unit].to_sym
```

If the above solves your problem, then you didn't have a symbol in there to start with (likely, if params has been read from an HTTP request)